# How recursively call subsequences in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, subsequence

I tried to make recursive function which call the subsequences and I had got some errors.

My Code:

```
recursive 1 list = subsequences list
recursive n list = subsequences (recursive (n-1) list)
```

Error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ [a1]
    Expected type: [a1]
      Actual type: [[a1]]

    Relevant bindings include
      recursive :: a -> t -> [[a1]] (bound at p.hs:6:1)
    In the first argument of ‘subsequences’, namely
      ‘(recursive (n - 1) list)’
    In the expression: subsequences (recursive (n - 1) list)
```

Could you help me to solve this problem or find another way to call subsequences n times?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: This function, as you've conceived it, cannot be written in Haskell. Try to write the type signature and you'll see why. You will need to change the representation of the nested result in order to implement it.

Comment: What is the expected output for some example inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't worked with polymorphic recursion much, so I wanted to try this.  Here's what I got:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Data.List (subsequences)

-- Any multiply-nested list such as a, [a], [[a]], [[[a]]], ...
data MultiList a
  = Leaf a
  | Nest (MultiList [a])
  deriving (Show, Functor)

recursive :: Int -> [a] -> MultiList [[a]]
recursive 1 list = Leaf (subsequences list)
recursive n list = Nest (fmap subsequences (recursive (n-1) list))
```

Comment: It's amazing how much easier polymorphic recursion is to read than to write. It does make certain kinds of things easier to think about though--induction tends to work very well, and parametricity is particularly strong--irrelevant things tend to fuzz out completely.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward with [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances, TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.List
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import qualified GHC.TypeLits as Lit

$(singletons [d| data Nat = Z | S Nat |])

type family Nested n a where
    Nested  Z    a = a
    Nested (S n) a = [Nested n a]

subsequenceses :: Sing n -> [a] -> [Nested n a]
subsequenceses  SZ     xs = xs
subsequenceses (SS sn) xs = subsequences (subsequenceses sn xs)

type family Lit i where
    Lit 0 = Z
    Lit n = S (Lit (n Lit.- 1))

type SLit n = Sing (Lit n)

main = print $ subsequenceses (sing :: SLit 2) [1..2]
```

`subsequenceses (sing :: SLit 0) xs` is `xs`

`subsequenceses (sing :: SLit 1) xs` is `subsequences xs`

`subsequenceses (sing :: SLit 2) xs` is `subsequences (subsequences xs)`

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If I call your function with 1, it will return a list of lists of elements. If I call it with 2, it will return a list of lists of lists of elements. In a dependently typed language, this would be fine, but Haskell is not dependently typed, so you will need to represent the result in some other way, encoding the depth in the result type.

Comment: It's a bit problematic cause i need to write as short code as it's possible. Maybe there is some way to make n-times long chain of subsequences calls (like `subsequences . subsequences . subsequences . ` ...etc) ?

Comment: @Legem, you could make that sort of thing work with fancy things like singletons, but I doubt it's worth the trouble. Changing result types would be much easier than that.